# Get the complete html code from an album of facebook

Tags: php, html, facebook, curl

I'm trying to get the html code from an album of facebook,once done that i want to extract the photo links,
 but as we know all the photos are not loaded at once but as you scroll down.

When i use cURL it get only those links of the photos which are loaded at first.

Will there be a way to get the whole loaded html code through php?

Please bear with my english.

Thanks

EDIT: Well i was wanting to do the same on any page which have this kind of behavior not only on facebook. Thanks anyway

Comment: You should be using the Facebook Graph API for this. The loading you describe is processed via JavaScript - PHP will not execute it.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to reliably fetch an album from Facebook via this method.

There are a small amount of photos sent with the original request and the rest are loaded via ajax. Using curl, there is no way that I am aware of to simulate the events that lead to said ajax load. You could call the original, and then subsequently call the other ajax endpoints but this method is likely to break the second fb changes anything.

As ceejayoz said, you should be using the fb api for this sort of thing.